# How to make exiftool not to change file's date and time

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, command-line-arguments, exiftool

How to make exiftool not to change the date and time of the affected files?

I mean not the date and time written in EXIF, I mean the date and time of the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I've just found the solution in the manual!

You should use -P option.

Great!